# Can I override u-strings (u'example') in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

In debugging upgrading to Python 3, it would be useful to be able to override the u'' string prefix to call my own function or replace with a non-u string.

I've tried things like `unichr = chr` which is useful for my debugging but doesn't accomplish the above.

`module.uprefix = str` is the type of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly you trying to do? It's unclear.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. In Python 3 `str` is equivalent to Python 2's `unicode` (which are "u-prefixed strings")

Comment: The u-prefix is handled by Python's bytecode compiler. The behavior could only be changed by modifying and compiling Python itself.

Comment: Purely for debugging purposes I want to dynamically change the behaviour of strings initialised with u'' in Python 2.

Comment: How about dynamically loading a module with the built in bytecode processing functions and replacing it there?

Comment: The important distinction in Python 3 isn't between unicode and string, but between string (unicode or not) and bytes. Modifying the behaviour of `u''` strings won't help there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can't; as others have noted in the comments, the u-prefix is handled very early, well before anything where an in-code assignment would take effect.

About the best you could do is use `ast.parse` to read a module on disk (without importing it) and find all the `u''` strings; it distinguishes the prefixes. That would help you find them in a Python-aware way, more reliably than just searching for `u'` and `u"`, but the difference probably wouldn't be large, especially if you search with word boundaries (regex `\bu['"]`). Unless you somehow have a lot of `u'` and `u"` in your program that aren't the prefixes?

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('"abc"', mode='eval'))
"Expression(body=Constant(value='abc', kind=None))"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('u"abc"', mode='eval'))
"Expression(body=Constant(value='abc', kind='u'))"
```

Per the comments, what are you trying to do? I've migrated a lot of code from Python 2 to Python 3 and never needed this... There may be a different way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Can I dynamically replace the entire <type 'unicode'>type with str type?

Comment: Not dynamically, no. You could use `ast.parse` to read the file, modify the data structure, then write out a new version without any of the `u` prefixes; however, since current versions of Python 3 all accept (and ignore) the `u` prefix, there wouldn't seem to be much advantage?

Comment: Also, if you're thinking of writing a tool to parse python 2 and write python 3... Python already comes with one, the [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) tool. It's not perfect, but it'll almost certainly be better than anything you can put together quickly. It has a whole bunch of options if the defaults don't quite work for your codebase.

Comment: In particular, `2to3` has specific handling for unicode -> str: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#to3fixer-unicode

Comment: PS: I assume you're familiar with the `six` library?